# If $\{j_n\}$ is increasing and $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\frac{j_n}n=+∞$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{j_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My friend gave me an interesting analysis problem, and I was tackling it but it was very hard indeed. Here is the problem:

> Let $j_1,j_2,j_3,\cdots$ be a sequence of strictly increasing positive integers such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{j_n}{n} = +\infty$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}}{j_n}$ converges.
>   Note: $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x.$

I think this is some hardcore analysis problem, I would really love to know how you solve this problem, and possibly a full out solution. I am trying my hardest to solve it too, and would appreciate any help offered.

**My attempt at proof of the above:**

We know that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{j_n\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}}=0$$ and clearly the summation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$$
converges, so we cann directly deduce that 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j_n\sqrt{n}}$ converges by the limit comparison test. Now, let $k_n =\frac{1}{j_n}$, and claim that $S_l=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{l}(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}k_n$ is Cauchy. Now we take the terms $S_l-S_{m-1}=\sum\limits_{n=m}^{l}(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}k_n$ in to consideration, and to bound the term from above, we delete all terms with $[\sqrt{n}]=[\sqrt{m}]$ if $[\sqrt{m}]$ is odd and insert all missing terms with $[\sqrt{m}] =  [\sqrt{n}]$ if  $[\sqrt{m}]$ is even. Hence for a fixed $l,$ taking $1< m < l$, there exists $n,s$ with $n\le s$ such that:
$$S_l-S_{m-1}=\sum\limits_{t=m}^{l}(-1)^{[\sqrt{t}]}k_t\le \sum\limits_{t=(2n)^2}^{(2s+1)^2-1}(-1)^{[\sqrt{t}]}k_t\le $$ $$\sum\limits_{t=(2n)^2}^{(2s+1)^2-1}k_t + \sum^s_{t=n+1}\bigg[2k_{(2t+1)^2-2}+\sum_{u=0}^{(2t)^2-(2t-1)^2-1}(k_{(2t)^2+u}-k_{(2t-1)^2=u})\bigg]$$
$$\le (4n+1)k_{(2n)^2}+\sum^{s}_{t=n+1}2k_{(2t+1)^2-2}\le (4n+1)k_{(2n)^2}+2\sum^s_{t=n+1}\frac{1}{8t}\sum^{(2t+1)^2-2}_{u=(2t-1)^2-1}k_u$$
$$\le (4n+1)k_{(2n)^2}+\sum^s_{t=n+1}\sum^{(2t+1)^2-2}_{u=(2t-1)^2-1}\frac{k_u}{\sqrt{u}}\le  (4n+1)k_{(2n)^2}+\sum^{(2s+1)^2-2}_{u=(2n+1)^2-1}\frac{k_u}{\sqrt{u}} $$

It is not hard to see that as $m \rightarrow \infty,$ $n \rightarrow \infty$. We finally claim that the last expression goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Note that the second term of the last expression tends to $0$ as as $n \rightarrow \infty$ as $\frac{k_u}{\sqrt{u}}$ converges. So it remains to show that the first term tends to $0$. We prove this by contradiction.

**Proof:** For some $\epsilon > 0,$ assume that $(4n+1)k_{(2n)^2} >\epsilon$ infinitely often. If we recursively take $n_t>2n_{t-1}$ for $t \ge 1,$ with $(4n+1)k_{(2n)^2}>\epsilon$, then:
$$\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \frac{k_l}{\sqrt{l}}\ge \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\sum_{u=n_t^2}^{(2n_t)^2}\frac{k_u}{\sqrt{u}}\le \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}3n_t^2 \frac{k_{(2n_t)^2}}{2n_t}=\frac{3}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{t=1}n_t k_{(2n_t)^2}$$ $$\ge \frac{3}{10}\sum^{\infty}_{t=1}(k_{(2n_t)^2} \ge \frac{3}{10}\sum^{\infty}_{u=1}\epsilon =+\infty$$

This is a clear contradiction. So $\lim_{l\rightarrow \infty}\sup\{S_l-S_{m-1}:m<l\}\le 0$. We can repeat the above with $S_l-S_{m-1}$ bounded from below and get $\lim_{l\rightarrow \infty}\inf\{S_l-S_{m-1}:m<l\}\ge 0$, hence clearly $ S_l$ is Cauchy and thus converges.

The reason I tried to come with a different idea is that I do not know what Dedekind's Test is, and even though I looked it up just so I can understand the accepted answer, it did not seem to make me fully satisfied. Although I am more aware of **Dirichlet's Criterion** for series. But of course I now come to realize that they are infact similar.

Comment: I think you might be able to solve this by looking at *random series*. Check out section 1.6 of book four of Stein and Shakarchi's analysis books. You can prove that many series that look like this one can converge by essentially showing that $\sum (\pm)1/n$ converges for "almost all'' choices of $\pm$ signs in a certain sense.

Comment: @AOrtiz I don't see how that works here. It's clear that $\sum\pm1/j_n$ is almost surely convergent. Now what?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I didn't check the details, and I am not sure this method works. I only recently discovered these ideas, and this question reminded me of what I had read, so I thought I would put it out there in case the OP or someone else wanted to look into it. Cheers

Comment: @AOrtiz It's not just that I don't see how to fill in the details in this example, I don't see how what you suggest could _possibly_ work, even in principle. Hence I suspect that S&S do not actually give any examples of the sort you suggest they do. I'm familiar withh using randomization in studying convergence of series of _functions_, or random variiables or whatever, but I don't see how randomization can _possibly_ show convergence of an explicit single series of _constants_. Do they actually give such an example? If so what? No detaiils, just tell me a single series that they do this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that we don't need the assumption that $j_n/n\to\infty$; I believe that the following is a proof, and unless I missed it I never used $j_n/n\to\infty$:

Say $$I_k=\{n:k^2\le n<(k+1)^2\}=\{n:[\sqrt n]=k\}.$$Let $$a_k=\sum_{n\in I_k}\frac1{j_n}.$$Since $j_n\ge n$ it's clear that $a_k\to0$.

I've been stuck on showing that $a_k$ is decreasing. If so then $\sum(-1)^ka_k$ converges, and it's not quite trivial but not hard to deduce from that that the original sum converges.

Wait - it's enough to show that the sequence $a_k$ has bounded variation.
Each term in $a_k$ can be matched with a corresponding smaller term in the definition of $a_{k+1}$: If $j\in I_k$ then $j'=j+2k+1\in I_{k+1}$, and $1/n_j\ge 1/n_{j'}$. There are two terms in $a_{k+1}$ left over; since $j_n\ge n$ it follows that $$a_k-a_{k+1}\ge-\frac c{k^2}.$$
So $\sum(a_k-a_{k+1})^-$ converges; since $\sum (a_k-a_{k+1})$ converges and $|t|=t+2t^-$ this shows $\sum|a_k-a_{k+1}|$ converges, qed.

**Details:** First, why do $a_k\to0$ and $\sum|a_k-a_{k+1}|<\infty$ imply that $\sum(-1)^ka_k$ converges? This is a simple generalization of the alternating series test, proved by summation by parts. In fact it's Someone's Test... (Or maybe not. I thought it was Dirichlet's Test, but looking it up that requires $a_{k+1}\le a_k$. In any case it follows easily from summation by parts. Or just note this: Let $$\sigma_K=\sum_{k=1}^K(-1)^ka_k.$$Then $\sigma_{2K}$ is a partial sum of the absolutely convergent series $\sum(a_{2k}-a_{2k-1})$, and $\sigma_{2K+1}-\sigma_{2K}\to0$.

**Edit:** Daniel Fischer tells us it's [Dedekind's Test](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dedekind_criterion_%28convergence_of_series%29). Unfortunately the statement there is wrong. The actual DT is this: If the partial sums of $\sum e_j$ are bounded, $b_j\to0$ and $\sum|b_{j+1}-b_j|<\infty$ then the series $\sum e_j b_j$ converges. The statement of Dedekind's Test at EOM omits the hypothesis that $b_j\to0$; taking $b_j=1$ and $e_j=(-1)^j$ shows that this  is nonsense.)

Second, why does convergence of one series imply convergence of the other?  Let $\sigma_K$ be as above and let $$s_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{j_n}.$$Then $$\sigma_K=s_{N_K},$$where $N_K=(K+1)^2-1$, so convergence of $s_N$ implies convergence of $\sigma_K$. Conversely, if $N_K<N<N_{K+1}$ then we have either $\sigma_K\le s_N\le\sigma_{K+1}$ or $\sigma_{K+1}\le s_N\le\sigma_K$, depending on whether $K$  is even or odd; hence convergence of $\sigma_K$ implies convergence of $s_N$.

But it's false if we don't assume the $j_n$ are increasing - I mention this because it's already typed up, I missed that hypothesis at first and posted a wrong counterexample. Define $$j_n=\begin{cases} k^2\log(k),&((2k)^2\le n<(2k+1)^2),
\\2k^2\log(k),&((2k+1)^2\le n<(2k+2)^2).\end{cases}$$

(No, $j_n$ is not an integer. If you really think that might matter take $j_n$ to be the integer part of what's defined above.)

Then if you look carefully at your series it seems to me it diverges, because the series $$\sum_k\sum_{n=(2k)^2}^{(2k+2)^2-1}\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{j_n}\sim\sum\left(\frac1{2k\log(k)}-\frac1{k\log(k)}\right)$$
diverges...

Comment: The "strictly increasing" may save it (and with that, it might be relevant that the $j_n$ are integers because that means the increase can't be too slow).

Comment: @DanielFischer In fact it seems clear that the $a_k$ above must be decreasing, in which case qed. Haven't quite proved it, two little terms dangling off the end of $a_k-a_{k+1}$...

Comment: @DanielFischer But those two terms don't matter. qed.

Comment: Nice argument. Beats fiddling around to show $$\sum_{k = 1}^{2n-1}\biggl(\frac{1}{j_{n^2}-k} - \frac{1}{j_{n^2} + k - 1}\biggr) \geqslant \frac{1}{j_{n^2} + 2n-1} + \frac{1}{j_{n^2}+2n}$$ (which might not be true) hands down.

Comment: It's Dedekind's test.

Comment: @DanielFischer Glad at least one person was able to follow the version I posted with no details late last night. Yes, noting that $a_k-a_{k+1}\ge -c/k^2$ is close enough is nicer. But, just to silence Hardy and Littlewood laughing at us from  their graves, I do think $a_k$ is decreasing. First, it's true if $j_n=n+\alpha$; in that case you can calculate $a_k$ "exactly. Now in general, choose $\alpha$ so that if $j_n'=n+\alpha$ then $j_n'=j_n$ for the $n$ where we switch from $a_k$ to $a_{k+1}$. Then $a_k\ge a_k'$ and $a_{k+1}\le a_{k+1}'$.

Comment: Yes, I too think $a_k$ is decreasing. But since I haven't fiddled, I'm cautious. And there are worse things than being laughed at by Hardy and Littlewood, I could live with that.

Comment: [EOM](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dedekind_criterion_%28convergence_of_series%29) has a coherent statement, better link to that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and answer. Now as much as I follow your argument, I have managed to come up with a proof where the series infact converges. I will upload my proof soon will take some time as I have to brush up on the details, but nevertheless I would appreciate the feedback.

Comment: "I have managed to come up with a proof where the series infact converges." I'm not sure what your point is, with the "in fact" - I already _gave_ a proof that the series converges.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, anyway can you take a look at my proof which I am writing up now, I understood your proof.